# How to retrieve the value of the an HTML table <td> using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to retrieve the value of the HTML table  using Vanilla Javascript

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the user clicks on the  tag, I would like to retrieve the value of the tag so that I know which one was clicked on using JS

Comment: If I understand your question, you can add an eventListener to each td element and do whatever you want with the value of the element. As a clue the event to listen is `click` and the "value" can be retrieved by event.target.innerText

Comment: oh btw we answered your question.. feel free to mark and or upvote us anytime :D

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to each `td`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td) => {
  td.onclick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);  // Do something useful here...
  };
});
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it would be much better to use event delegation with a table and set a single listener on the `tbody` (although you didn't include it, it is there in the rendered page).

Comment: @RandyCasburn ur problem is that he answered not how u would want it? :l

Comment: No, it was a comment. If I didn't like the answer I would have said "your answer sucks" - but I didn't do that. Setting event listeners on TD's is a serious code smell when one of the most basic features of the eventing system is designed to overcome the need for them. I was simply point out an alternative.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I see what you are saying and it might be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handle_TD_click(ev){
  var selectedTD=ev.path[0]
  //you can do anything with this.. I'm just gonna console.log its innerText
  console.log(selectedTD.innerText)
}
[...document.all] //for all elements in a document
.forEach(a=>{
  if(a.tagName=="TD"){a.addEventListener('click',handle_TD_click)} //if the tagName(out of all document tags) is a td element, event listener is added
})
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code throws and doesn't work. And is terrible inefficient to boot.

Comment: @RandyCasburn how so though? it works perfectly on my computer

Comment: It's your use of the non-standard `path` array. [Reference](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, using event delegation will allow the use of only one event handler. In this case the `click` event is handed on the table body.

In order for this to work this code is necessary to ensure only the contents of the TD are returned.

`if (e.target.nodeName !== 'TD') return;`

To get the value of the TD, use `.textContent` on the event target (`e.target`).

Here is the solution:

```js
function logValue(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'TD') return;
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
}

document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', logValue);
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```